# Are number operations using Kotlin as fast as the equivalent with Java primitives?

Tags: java, jvm, kotlin, primitive

Java has primitives because using them leads to more [efficient, readable, and less error prone code](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/203970/when-to-use-primitive-vs-class-in-java) than their class based counterparts.

Does Kotlin perform compile time optimizations to ensure that number operations perform at the same level (Or better) as Java primitives would?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Kotlin uses primitives as well. But note that:

1. Reasons for "less error-prone" don't really apply in Kotlin: the boxed types aren't nullable unless you ask for it (just like the primitives) and you can't confuse `==` and `equals`.
2. Neither do the "more readable": you can use operators with both.
3. The "more efficient" part does very much apply, but you can't make the one-character typographical error mentioned in the top answer to the linked question: you have to write `java.lang.Long` to get the boxed type!

On the other hand, you need to be aware of `IntArray` being more efficient than `Array<Int>` (the correspond to Java `int[]` and `java.lang.Integer[]`) despite both appearing to use `Int`.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html):

> Some of the types can have a special internal representation - for example, numbers, characters and booleans can be represented as primitive values at runtime - but to the user they look like ordinary classes. In this section we describe the basic types used in Kotlin: numbers, characters, booleans, arrays, and strings.

So yes, the compiler does optimise in a way that the [JVM primitive types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html) are used at runtime. There are certain exceptions of course:

> On the Java platform, numbers are physically stored as JVM primitive types, unless we need a nullable number reference (e.g. Int?) or generics are involved. In the latter cases numbers are boxed.

There's also a hint in the source documentation, e.g. `Int`:

> Represents a 32-bit signed integer. On the JVM, non-nullable values of this type are represented as values of the primitive type int.